# Writing to Windows CMD from Java

Tags: java, cmd, process, outputstream, processbuilder

I'm trying to be able to input commands into the command prompt on Windows from Java. I use processBuilder, open the command prompt, and get the output stream, but when I try to write to that, nothing seems to happen. Do I need to include something else, or am I going about this all wrong?

I know that I can pass arguments including commands into the command prompt when I initially start it, but my goal is to be able to open the window *first*, then interact with it *second*, not at the same time.

My code:

```
    ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    commands.add("cmd.exe");
    commands.add("/c");
    commands.add("start");

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);

    Process p = pb.start();

    BufferedWriter stdin = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

    stdin.write("dir");
    stdin.newLine();
    stdin.flush();
```

I've tried searching, but I haven't found any satisfactory answers. This code is what I've managed to piece together from that search.
My end goal is to be able to write a user interface for youtube-dl, a command line program, so I can get more experienced with such things. I'd like the user to be able to pick from several options, then execute the program based on their selection.

Comment: That is not how things work.  The output stream is redirected to the stdin of whatever program you execute.  The cmd.exe shell reads directly from the "terminal" (keyboard) and does not take input from stdin, so you cannot do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I see, thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: Interacting with a shell is extremely difficult due to timing and interpreting output intended for human consumption.  This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Explain what you're _really_ trying to accomplish.

Comment: My end goal is to be able to write a user interface for youtube-dl, a command line program, so I can get more experienced with such things. I'd like the user to be able to pick from several options, then execute the program based on their selection. I've also added this to the original post.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to do manually the youtube-dl thing, since youtube dl thing is an automatic script that uses a lot of CMD Commands.

Back to the topic, use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec()
```