# command prompt does not display the commands run from java

Tags: java

I have opened the command prompt from java and I am running `cd`command multiple times using `ProcessBuilder` class. The command prompt opens in my current directory but the `cd` commands are not being displayed on window. My eclipse console displays the changed directory.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe","/k","start");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = null;
            try {
                p = builder.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             BufferedWriter p_stdin = 
                      new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
             
             int n=3;
                for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                    try {
                        //single execution
                    p_stdin.write("cd..");
                    p_stdin.newLine();
                    p_stdin.flush();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
                
                Scanner s = new Scanner( p.getInputStream() );
                while (s.hasNext())
                {
                    System.out.println( s.next() );
                }
                   s.close();
```

**Output on console :**

> C:\Users\I309719\Desktop\selenium\workspace\Command_Prompt>cd..
>
> C:\Users\I309719\Desktop\selenium\workspace>cd..
>
> C:\Users\I309719\Desktop\selenium>cd..

[image: A new window opens]

Why is the flush not getting print on the opened window?

Comment: See comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41010603/3284624) basically you're not interacting with cmd, cmd doesn't take input from stdin.